# scala vs java, performance and memory?

Tags: java, performance, scala, memory

I am keen to look into Scala, and have one basic question I cant seem to find an answer to:
in general, is there a difference in performance and usage of memory between Scala and Java?

Comment: I have heard claims the performance can be very close. I suspect it is highly dependant on what you are doing. (as it is for Java vs C)

Comment: The answer to these sorts of questions is "it depends" - for virtually any comparison of system X vs system Y.  Plus, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479819/how-well-does-scala-perform-compared-to-java?rq=1

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Scala makes it very easy to use enormous amounts of memory without realizing it.  This is usually very powerful, but occasionally can be annoying.  For example, suppose you have an array of strings (called `array`), and a map from those strings to files (called `mapping`).  Suppose you want to get all files that are in the map and come from strings of length greater than two.  In Java, you might

```
int n = 0;
for (String s: array) {
  if (s.length > 2 && mapping.containsKey(s)) n++;
}
String[] bigEnough = new String[n];
n = 0;
for (String s: array) {
  if (s.length <= 2) continue;
  bigEnough[n++] = mapping.get(s);
}
```

Whew!  Hard work.  In Scala, the most compact way to do the same thing is:

```
val bigEnough = array.filter(_.length > 2).flatMap(mapping.get)
```

Easy!  But, unless you're fairly familiar with how the collections work, what you might not realize is that this way of doing this created an extra intermediate array (with `filter`), and an extra object for *every element of the array* (with `mapping.get`, which returns an option).  It also creates two function objects (one for the filter and one for the flatMap), though that is rarely a major issue since function objects are small.

So basically, the memory usage is, at a primitive level, the same.  But Scala's libraries have many powerful methods that let you create enormous numbers of (usually short-lived) objects very easily.  The garbage collector is usually pretty good with that kind of garbage, but if you go in completely oblivious to what memory is being used, you'll probably run into trouble sooner in Scala than Java.

Note that the Computer Languages Benchmark Game Scala code is written in a rather Java-like style in order to get Java-like performance, and thus has Java-like memory usage.  You can do this in Scala: if you write your code to look like high-performance Java code, it will be high-performance Scala code.  (You *may* be able to write it in a more idiomatic Scala style and still get good performance, but it depends on the specifics.)

I should add that per amount of time spent programming, my Scala code is usually *faster* than my Java code since in Scala I can get the tedious not-performance-critical parts done with less effort, and spend more of my attention optimizing the algorithms and code for the performance-critical parts.

Comment: +1 for that final paragraph. It's a vital point that's left out of consideration *far* too often.

Comment: I thought that [views](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) could help a lot with the issues you mention. Or is not true with arrays, specifically?

Comment: @Zwirb - Views help sometimes.  The view isn't going to help the generation of a zillion `Option`s in this example, which is the primary concern here unless almost nothing gets through the filter.  But they're definitely worth knowing about and using in appropriate situations.

Comment: @Kevin Wright - "It's a vital point that's left out of consideration far too often" - It's something that's easy to say and hard to demonstrate, and tell's us something about Rex Kerr's skills not what others less skilled achieve.

Comment: >>You *may* be able to write it in a more idiomatic Scala style and still get good performance<< There's room in the benchmarks game for those not written like Java programs, if someone contributes them ;-)

Comment: @igouy - The current benchmarks are not conducive to writing in idiomatic style with superlative performance.  That would require tests that involve a lot of high-level manipulations; as it is, the complex part is the low-level algorithms, not applying a simple low-level algorithm in sophisticated ways.

Comment: >>in idiomatic style with superlative performance<< There's room in the benchmarks game for idiomatic Scala programs which do not achieve "superlative" performance.

Comment: @igouy - I know, I know, but there isn't a score for _elegance_, and spending a long time to make a tiny program that is only moderately comprehensible is also not very rewarding (even if it does help push one to the nice corner of the code used/time used plots).  So no promises from me, but there are many other Scala users.

Comment: @Rex Kerr - there isn't a score for *elegance* - Imagine the squabbling if there was! I don't understand why idiomatic Scala programs would have to be "tiny" and as a consequence "only moderately comprehensible"? You'll know what programs for those tasks you'd consider idiomatic Scala - and once those idiomatic programs are published, I think there are going to be programmers curious enough to read them.

Comment: @RexKerr - doesn't your Java example lookup the mapping key twice for each possible String where your Scala example only does it once after the Strings have been selected?  I.e. they are optimised in different ways for different data sets?

Comment: @Seth - That is one of a number of differences, yes.  I was going for fairly idiomatic code in each case (starting with an array).

Comment: You can easy do it in Scala without introducing the extra intermediate array using lazy evaluation: `val bigEnough = array.view.filter(_.length > 2).flatMap(mapping.get).toArray`

Comment: @Chris - Indeed, Nicholas made the same point (without code) on May 5, 2011.  But note that I said "most compact" when describing the Scala solution (and note also my reply to Nicholas).

Comment: With java 8 streams the difference is quite small, I think

Comment: everybody here comparing Scala with Java7 or prior. Compare with java8 and you will find Java8 is much faster than Scala

Comment: @Sarang - No, that's just plain wrong.  Scala produces bytecode for the very same JVM that Java 8 uses, and, except in very rare instances when the bytecode is slightly less easily optimized (and therefore is slightly slower), delivers exactly the same performance.  (If you choose to use performance-minded packages in Java, but performance-ignoring ones in Scala, of course Java will look faster.  Scala will look faster if you do the opposite.)

Answer (score 110):

I'm a new user, so I'm not able to add a comment to Rex Kerr's answer above (allowing new users to "answer" but not "comment" is a very odd rule btw).

I signed up simply to respond to the "phew, Java is so verbose and such hard work" insinuation of Rex's popular answer above.  While you can of course write more concise Scala code, the Java example given is clearly bloated.  Most Java developers would code something like this:

```
List<String> bigEnough = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : array) {
  if(s.length() > 2 && mapping.get(s) != null) {
    bigEnough.add(mapping.get(s));
  }
}
```

And of course, if we are going to pretend that Eclipse doesn't do most of the actual typing for you and that every character saved really makes you a better programmer, then you could code this:

```
List b=new ArrayList();
for(String s:array)
  if(s.length()>2 && mapping.get(s) != null) b.add(mapping.get(s));
```

Now not only did I save the time it took me to type full variable names and curly braces (freeing me to spend 5 more seconds to think deep algorithmic thoughts), but I can also enter my code in obfuscation contests and potentially earn extra cash for the holidays.

Comment: How come you are not a member of the "hip language of the month" club? Nice comments. I particularly enjoyed reading the last paragraph.

Comment: Superbly put! I grow weary of contrived examples whereby inflated Java code is followed by some carefully constructed, terse example of Scala (or some other FP language) and then a hastily drawn conclusion that Scala must be better than Java because of it. Who ever wrote anything significant in Scala anyway! ;-) And don't say Twitter...

Comment: Socrates once asked, "is it good because you like it, or do you like it because it's good?" Java is just not that verbose, people just get bored when stuff gets dependable. I'll stick with Java for my enterprise systems.

Comment: Well, Rex's solution preallocates the memory for the array, which will make the _compiled code_ run faster (because with your approach, you let the JVM periodically reallocate your array as it grows). Even though there was more typing involved, performance-wise it could be a winner.

Comment: while we at it, in java8 it will be: `Arrays.stream(array).map(mapping::get).filter(x->x!=null).toArray(File[]::new);`

Comment: What makes Scala "better" in some ways than Java is the expanded type-system capabilities that make it easier to express more generic patterns as types (such as Monads, Functors, etc.).  This allows you to create types that don't get in your way due to overly strict contracts, as often happens in Java.  Strict contracts not based on actual patterns in the code are the reason Inversion of Responsibility patterns are necessary just to properly unit test your code (Dependence Injection comes to mind first and the XML Hell it brings).

The addl. conciseness the flexibility brings is just a bonus.

Answer (score 69):

Write your Scala like Java, and you can expect almost identical bytecode to be emitted - with almost identical metrics.

Write it more "idiomatically", with immutable objects and higher order functions, and it'll be a bit slower and a bit larger.  The one exception to this rule-of-thumb is when using generic objects in which the type params use the `@specialised` annotation, this'll create even larger bytecode that can outpace Java's performance by avoiding boxing/unboxing.

Also worth mentioning is the fact that more memory / less speed is an inevitable trade-off when writing code that can be run in parallel.  Idiomatic Scala code is far more declarative in nature than typical Java code, and is often a mere 4 characters (`.par`) away from being fully parallel.

So if

- Scala code takes 1.25x longer than Java code in a single thread
- It can be *easily* split across 4 cores (now common even in laptops)
- for a parallel run time of (1.24 / 4 =) 0.3125x the original Java

Would you then say that the Scala code is now comparatively 25% slower, or 3x faster?

The correct answer depends on exactly how you define "performance" :)

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to mention that `.par` is in 2.9.

Comment: @Rex - No need, you just did it for me :)

Comment: >>Would you then say that the Scala code is now comparatively 25% slower, or 3x faster?<< I'd say why isn't your hypothetical comparison to multi-threaded Java code?

Comment: @igouy - The point is that said hypothetical code doesn't exist, the imperative nature of the "faster" Java code makes it much harder to parallelise, such that the cost/benefit ratio means it's unlikely to happen at all.  Idiomatic Scala, on the other hand, being far more declarative in nature can frequently be made concurrent with no more than a trivial change.

Comment: Here's a Java fannkuch-redux program that does exist http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=fannkuchredux&lang=java&id=1, and a Scala fannkuch-redux program that does exist http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=fannkuchredux&lang=scala&id=2 - the "parallel run time" of the Scala program is not a fraction of the Java run time.

Comment: The existence of concurrent Java programs does not imply that a *typical* Java program can be easily adapted to concurrency.  If anything, I'd say that particular fork-join style is particularly rare in Java and has to be explicitly coded, whereas simple operations such as finding the minimum contained value, or the sum of values in a collection can be trivially done in parallel in Scala by simply using `.par`.

Comment: Might you also say that - the existence of trivial operations such as finding the minimum contained value, or the sum of values in a collection, does not imply that a *typical* Scala program can be trivially done in parallel by simply using `.par` ?

Comment: No, I might not. This sort of thing is a fundamental building block for many algorithms, and to see it present at such a low level in the language and standard libraries (the same standard libraries that all programs will use, not just typical ones) is evidence that you're already closer to being concurrent by simply choosing the language.  For example, mapping over a collection is inherently suitable to parallelisation, and the number of Scala programs that don't use the `map` method will be vanishingly small.

Comment: This is an old answer, but would you say that Java 8 parallel streams give Java a performance edge vs. Scala?

Answer (score 36):

Computer Language Benchmarks Game:

[Speed test](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/scala.html) java/scala 1.71/2.25

[Memory test](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-language-is-best.php?calc=chart&gpp=on&java=on&scala=on&sbcl=on&ghc=on&csharp=on&hipe=on&python3=on&yarv=on&xfullcpu=0&xmem=1&xloc=0&nbody=1&fannkuchredux=1&meteor=0&fasta=1&spectralnorm=1&revcomp=1&mandelbrot=1&knucleotide=1&regexdna=1&pidigits=1&chameneosredux=0&threadring=0&binarytrees=1) java/scala 66.55/80.81

So, this benchmarks say that java is 24% faster and scala uses 21% more memory.

All-in-all it's no big deal and should not matter in real world apps, where most of the time is consumed by database and network.

**Bottom line:** If Scala makes you and your team (and people taking project over when you leave) more productive, then you should go for it.

Comment: [Code size](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-language-is-best.php?calc=chart&gpp=on&ghc=on&csharp=on&sbcl=on&yarv=on&python3=on&java=on&hipe=on&xfullcpu=0&xmem=0&xloc=1&nbody=1&fannkuchredux=1&meteor=0&fasta=1&spectralnorm=1&revcomp=1&mandelbrot=1&knucleotide=1&regexdna=1&pidigits=1&chameneosredux=0&threadring=0&binarytrees=1) java/scala 3.39/2.21

Comment: Be careful with numbers like these, they sound awfully precise while in reality they mean almost nothing. It's not as if Scala is always 24% faster than Java on average, etc.

Comment: Afaik cited numbers indicate the opposite: Java is 24% faster than scala. But as you say - they're microbenchmarks, which needn't match what is happening in real apps. And the different way or problem solution in different languages might lead to less comparable programs in the end.

Comment: "If Scala makes you and your team..." Bottom line: You'll know that after not before :-)

Comment: The benchmarks game Help page provides an example of how to "Compare program speed and size for 2 language implementations". For Scala and Java the appropriate comparison web page is - http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/scala.php

Comment: @igouy - After what?  Once you've done a couple of trial projects in Scala it should be possible to make comparative estimates between Scala and Java *before* starting another project - the same as with any other two alternate technologies.

Comment: @igouy - Rats.  Looks like I need to rewrite k-nucleotide again one of these days.  Its performance is unnecessarily embarrassing.

Comment: @Rex Kerr - But I was hoping for those *more idiomatic Scala* not written like Java programs :-)

Comment: @hammar Only if the improvement of code size does improve readability and therefore maintainability.

Answer (score 21):

Others have answered this question with respect to tight loops although there seems to be an obvious performance difference between Rex Kerr's examples that I have commented on.

This answer is really targeted at people who might investigate a need for tight-loop optimisation as design flaw.

I am relatively new to Scala (about a year or so) but the feel of it, thus far, is that it allows you to *defer* many aspects of design, implementation and execution relatively easily (with enough background reading and experimentation :)

**Deferred Design Features:**

- [Abstract Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/105)
- [Explicitly Typed Self References](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124)
- [Views](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130)
- [Mixins](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/117)

**Deferred Implementation Features:**

- [Variance Annotations](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129)
- [Compound Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/110)
- [Local Type Inference](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/127)

**Deferred Execution Features:** (sorry, no links)

- Thread-safe lazy values
- Pass-by-name
- Monadic stuff

These features, to me, are the ones that help us to tread the path to fast, tight applications.

---

Rex Kerr's examples differ in what aspects of execution are deferred.  In the Java example, allocation of memory is deferred until it's size is calculated where the Scala example defers the mapping lookup. To me, they seem like completely different algorithms.

Here's what I think is more of an apples to apples equivalent for his Java example:

```
val bigEnough = array.collect({
    case k: String if k.length > 2 && mapping.contains(k) => mapping(k)
})
```

No intermediary collections, no `Option` instances etc.
This also preserves the collection type so `bigEnough`'s type is `Array[File]` - `Array`'s `collect` implementation will probably be doing something along the lines of what Mr Kerr's Java code does.

The deferred design features I listed above would also allow Scala's collection API developers to implement that fast Array-specific collect implementation in future releases without breaking the API. This is what I'm referring to with treading the path to speed.

Also:

```
val bigEnough = array.withFilter(_.length > 2).flatMap(mapping.get)
```

The `withFilter` method that I've used here instead of `filter` fixes the intermediate collection problem but there is still the Option instance issue.

---

One example of simple execution speed in Scala is with logging.

In Java we might write something like:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
    logger.debug("trace");
```

In Scala, this is just:

```
logger.debug("trace")
```

because the message parameter to debug in Scala has the type "`=> String`" which I think of as a parameter-less function that executes when it is evaluated, but which the documentation calls pass-by-name.

EDIT {
Functions in Scala are objects so there is an extra object here. For my work, the weight of a trivial object is worth removing the possibility of a log message getting needlessly evaluated.
}

This doesn't make the code faster but it does make it more likely to be faster and we're less likely to have the experience of going through and cleaning up other people's code en masse.

To me, this is a consistent theme within Scala.

---

Hard code fails to capture why Scala is faster though it does hint a bit.

I feel that it's a combination of code re-use and the ceiling of code quality in Scala.

In Java, awesome code is often forced to become an incomprehensible mess and so isn't really viable within production quality APIs as most programmers wouldn't be able to use it.

I have high hopes that Scala could allow the einsteins among us to implement far more competent APIs, potentially expressed through DSLs. The core APIs in Scala are already far along this path.

Comment: Your logging stuff is a good example for the performance pitfalls of Scala: logger.debug("trace") creates a new object for the parameter-less function.

Comment: Indeed - how does that affect my associated point?

Comment: The aforementioned objects can also be used to make transparent IoC control structures for the sake of efficiency. Yes, the same result is theoretically possible in Java but it would be something that dramatically affected/obfuscated the way code is written - hence my argument that Scala's knack for deferring many elements of software development helps us move towards faster code - more likely to be faster in practice vs having marginally faster unit performance.

Comment: Ok, I've re-read this and I did write, "simple execution speed" - I will add a note. Good point  :)

Comment: Predictable if statement (basically free on a superscalar processor) vs object allocation + garbage. The Java code is obviously faster (note it only evaluates the condition, execution won't reach the log statement.) In response to "For my work, the weight of a trivial object is worth removing the possibility of a log message getting needlessly evaluated."

Comment: I agree with @Eloff although it doesn't apply to ARM. Generational GC & object pooling will mean that memory allocation and collection is unlikely, and that there is decent locality of reference. It's hard to get around that sort of compromise without using something like C++

Answer (score 11):

[@higherkinded](http://twitter.com/higherkinded)´s presentation on the subject - [Scala Performance Considerations](https://docs.google.com/present/printview?id=ddmmbr8g_11fp6dq96s) which does some Java/Scala comparisions.

Tools:

- [ScalaMeter](http://scalameter.github.io/)
- [scala-benchmarking-template](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-benchmarking-template)

Great blogpost:

- [Nanotrusting the Nanotime](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/)

Answer (score 10):

Java and Scala both compile down to JVM bytecode, so the difference isn't that big. The best comparison you can get is probably on the [computer language benchmarks game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/scala.html), which essentially says that Java and Scala both have the same memory usage. Scala is only *slightly* slower than Java on some of the benchmarks listed, but that could simply be because the implementation of the programs are different.

Really though, they're both so close it's not worth worrying about. The productivity increase you get by using a more expressive language like Scala is worth so much more than minimal (if any) performance hit.

Comment: I see a logical fallacy here: Both languages compile down to bytecode, but an experienced programmer and a newbie - their code compiles down to bytecode too - but not to the same bytecode, so the conclusion, that the difference can't be that big, can be wrong. And in fact, in former times, a while-loop could be much, much faster in scala than a semantically equivalent for-loop (if I remember correctly, it is much better today). And both was compiled to bytecode, of course.

Comment: @user unknown - "a while-loop could be much, much faster in scala than a semantically equivalent for-loop" - notice that those Scala benchmarks game programs are written with while loops.

Comment: @igouy: I didn't talk about results from this microbenchmark, but about the argumentation. A true statement `Java and Scala both compile down to JVM bytecode, ` which was combined with a `so` to the statement in question `diffence isn't that big.` I wanted to show, that the `so` is just a rhetorical trick, and not an argumentative conclusion.

Comment: surprisingly incorrect answer with surprisingly high votes.

Answer (score 4):

The Java example is really not an idiom for typical application programs.
Such optimized code might be found in a system library method. But then it would use an array of the right type, i.e. File[] and would not throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. (Different filter conditions for counting and adding). 
My version would be (always (!) with curly braces because I don't like to spend an hour searching a bug which was introduced by saving the 2 seconds to hit a single key in Eclipse):

```
List<File> bigEnough = new ArrayList<File>();
for(String s : array) {
  if(s.length() > 2) {
    File file = mapping.get(s);
    if (file != null) {
      bigEnough.add(file);
    }
  }
}
```

But I could bring you a lot of other ugly Java code examples from my current project. I tried to avoid the common copy&modify style of coding by factoring out common structures and behaviour.

In my abstract DAO base class I have an abstract inner class for the common caching mechanism. For every concrete model object type there is a subclass of the abstract DAO base class, in which the inner class is subclassed to provide an implementation for the method which creates the business object when it is loaded from the database. (We can not use an ORM tool because we access another system via a proprietary API.)

This subclassing and instantiation code is not at all clear in Java and would be very readable in Scala.